# Passive wait until time elapses in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, animation, matlab-figure

I am creating a real-time MATLAB animation. This means that I want to update a figure with respect to the real world clock time. For example, let's say that I want to update the figure every 0.5 seconds. I know of `tic` and `toc`, which will allow me to measure real world clock time. However, I do not want to iterate uselessly in a loop until for example `toc>=0.5` is satisfied - rather, I want to do the more efficient "passive wait". Here's pseudo-code of my idea:

```
while (some break condition)
   x = tic;
   passive wait until toc>=0.5
   // update figure
   // update break condition
end
```

Could you please help me on how to do this in MATLAB?

Comment: take a look at [`pause`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pause.html)

Comment: pause does not do what I want. An active wait solution to my problem is `while toc < seconds
end` but this is just horrible! I'm looking for an equivalent passive wait solution - which does not iterate the while loop a billion times before the condition is satisfied.

Comment: Why does `pause` not do what you want? It fits perfectly given your problem description.

Comment: I just realized that it is. `pause(0.5)` does it.